# Android Studio text is messed up (corrupted) after plugin installation

Tags: android, android-studio

The problem is android studio suggested a plugin installation for README.md files and after that this is what happened

[image]

I don't know what happened with Android Studio font but it is all messed up like this.

*however all project files are completely fine*

**Problem in detail :**

Android Studio suggested a plugin installation for .md files which I accepted and then another prompt popped up which said other plugins need to be installed (as a dependency) so the suggested plugin work and I accepted it and then restart Android Studio for the changes to take effect. Before Android Studio started again, it prompted me with a message

`That only one these two plugins could run at the same time`

`- MarkDown jetbrains
 - MarkDown something else(I don't remember)`

I chose the first one and after that Android Studio started again and here was the problem.

**What I've tried**

- I tried to delete the said plugins but nothing changed
- I deleted `.AndroidStudio` folder in `C:\Users\myname` which actually worked but then when I tried to import my settings.jar file which I made last month and the problem showed up again

***How do I solve this?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by not importing below option

[image]